# Using MongoDB and Relational DB together

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions

How to handle transaction issues in an environment where [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) databases work together?

I want to use [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) for scalability and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) for transactions. (transactions are used in the inventory management system but product information is stored in a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database)

Comment: What do you mean by scalability? MySQL also provides a Document Store interface somewhat similar to MongoDB (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html). Maybe you can use just a single database engine and that ceases to be a problem. Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js.

Comment: @ruiquelhas thank you very much for your answer. Scalability means, adding more product types into the DB without empty fields. In relational DBs, there can be empty fields for some products. Eg Apparel and Electronics products have different attributes.

Answer (score 2):

There is good news: As of Mongo version 4.2, multiple document ACID transactions are now [fully supported](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/):

> For situations that require atomicity of reads and writes to multiple documents (in a single or multiple collections), MongoDB supports multi-document transactions.

As a general comment to your question, there is nothing wrong with having more than one data store in your architecture.  However, keep in mind that business operations which would require both Mongo and MySQL for a single logical transaction/unit, there would probably be no way to make this atomic.  If you are falling into this category, then you need to rethink your database design, and just stick with one database for each business operation.

Comment: Hi, what about doing it like this? Is this okay? (sorry for the formatting)

        public async Task BeginTransactionAsync()
        {
            mongoDbSession = await mongoDbClient.StartSessionAsync();
            surgicalDbTransaction = surgicalDbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public async Task CommitAsync()
        {
            await mongoDbSession.CommitTransactionAsync();
            await surgicalDbTransaction.CommitAsync();
        }